# Length of headsepline wrong when using BCOR and geometry

Tags: koma-script, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=12mm, headsepline]{scrbook}


\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.5pt:\textwidth}

\usepackage{geometry} % all okay of geometry not loaded


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The length of the headsepline is just the amount of `BCOR` too short. But only when the `geometry` package is loaded.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is also correct, if you comment out the `\KOMAoption`-command.

Answer (score 6):

Change the order to

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.5pt:\textwidth}
```

---

**Explanation**

```
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.5pt:\textwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

uses the `\textwidth` that was calculated by `typearea` before package `geometry` is loaded.

Note that loading `geometry` changes the page layout even if there are no options for margins etc.

The following example uses a larger `BCOR` and a thicker `headsepline` to show the difference:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=60mm, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 

\KOMAoption{headsepline}{5pt:\textwidth}
\usepackage[
  %pass % disables calculations by geometry
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can avoid the recalculation of the page layout using `geometry` option `pass`. If you enable this option in the example above you will get

[image]

If you compare the results you can see that package `geometry` also disables at least option `BCOR` and option `headinclude` which was automatically set by class option `headsepline.

So if you want to use package `geometry` (to set the margins?) then you have to use the options of this package to set a binding offset and maybe to include the head in the total body.

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 

\usepackage[
  bindingoffset=60mm,
  includehead
  ]{geometry}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{5pt:\textwidth}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With your example:

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 

\usepackage[
  bindingoffset=12mm,
  includehead
  ]{geometry}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{.5pt:\textwidth}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Several KOMA-Script options like `BCOR` or `DIV` and the command `\recalctypearea` change the page layout too. So it could be a good idea to use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.5pt:\textwidth}}
```

Note that `\textwidth` could be changed inside the document too. If the length of `\headsepline` should then be adjusted automatically use

```
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt:\textwidth}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt:\textwidth}}
%% if there could be also a plain headsepline:
%\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{plain.scrheadings}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt:\textwidth}}

\usepackage[
  bindingoffset=12mm,
  includehead
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\newgeometry{margin=5cm}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! But my problem is a bit more complicated. I wrote a class wrapping around `scrbook` and also set the headsepline. But know somebody using the class loads the package. How can I anticipate that? `\RequirePackage{geometry}` athough I don't really need it? `\AtBeginDocument{\KOMAoption{...}}`?

Comment: I have added a suggestion for later changes of the page layout. But if the length of `headsepline` should be really `\textwidth` the simplest solution is using the answer of @Jan.

Comment: @essd: Thank you :-)  But your answer ist really enlighting.  I have learned a lot from it.  That's why we are here, aren't we?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have to set the width of the line by using it this way:

```
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{7pt}
```

At least this MWE works to me:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=12mm, headsepline]{scrbook}


\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.7pt}

\usepackage{geometry} % all okay of geometry not loaded


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as well. But KOMA docs mentions it should be possible to set length and width with `\KOMAoption{headsepline}{width:length}`.  The observation is, that length seems to be off when using geometry and BCOR.